# Join existing linux user to AD domain

Tags: linux, domain, usermod

I succesfully join fedora and ubuntu thanks to realmd package.
After I join the machine I can also log with a domain user with no problem.
What I'd like to do now is to move and existing local user to a domain one.
I found usermod useful to change a local username. Here is the command:

```
sudo usermod --login newuser --home /home/newuser -m olduser
```

Then I just need to modify /etc/passwd and replace what's left about 'olduser' with 'newuser'.

However, renaming the username to a domain user is not enough: it will be a local user anyway with a local password.
How do I make an existing user a domain user ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a domain account named the same, edit the uidNumber attribute to match the local UID using Attribute Editor in AD / on Windows... Make sure to also set gidNumber for primary group, set homedir and the like...

This works at least on RHEL using SSSD...

Comment: I have no UNIX attributes enabled in AD yet. I was thinking about a temporary solution similar to time machine in my case: I should backup everything on an external HD and then restore it to the domain joined user home. Thanks

Comment: What version of AD? Server 2008R2+ already have the attributes...

Comment: Yup, go to the user in AD and click on the unix attributes tab. You may have to enable advanced views in AD Users and Computers for this to work.